# I need to have some fields in ui-schema which do not exist in schema section

Tags: json, reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I used to use [jsonform](http://github.com/jsonform/jsonform/wiki) in my project but now I migrate to react, So I use this library ([react-jsonschema-form](http://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form)). 
in jsonform I can have some fieldsets in form section that weren't  in schema. like this :

```
{
  "schema":
    {
      "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Is JSON Form useful?",
      }
    },
  "form": [
     {
      "key": "firstName",
      "type": "text",
     }, 
     {
      "title" : "this is non-schema",
      "type": "fieldset"
     }
   ]
}
```

you can test it at [jsonschema playground](http://ulion.github.io/jsonform/playground/).
please help me to do something like above code in [react-jsonschema-form](http://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form). 
how can I have some fields that aren't in schema but I want to show them in uiSchema?

react-jsonschema-form has a [playground](http://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/) too. You can find a field named 'date'. It adds in uiSchema but it doesn't exist in schema section. Also nothing shows for this field in the result. I don't know why they use it if it couldn't be there!!!!

thanks.

Comment: A little confused here.A UI schema is basically an object literal providing information on how the form should be rendered, while the JSON schema tells what.So,if it's not in sechema, it can't show in uiSchma.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I know but in jsonform that I put the link for you, you can have a fieldset without any schema field. please do it with playground to understand me better

Comment: I make an answer.Hope to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is just an example for uiSchema, and the playground just don't use it this time.And there I create an example to help understanding.

JSONSchema

```
{
  "title": "An example form",
  "description": "A simple form example",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "First name"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer",
      "title": "Age"
    },
    "telephone": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Telephone",
      "minLength": 10
    },
    "date": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Date"
    }
  }
}
```

UISchema

```
{
  "firstName": {
    "ui:autofocus": true,
    "ui:emptyValue": ""
  },
  "age": {
    "ui:widget": "updown",
    "ui:title": "Age of person",
    "ui:description": "(earthian year)"
  },
  "date": {
    "ui:widget": "alt-datetime"
  },
  "telephone": {
    "ui:options": {
      "inputType": "tel"
    }
  }
}
```

There are four in properties in JSONSchema:firstName, age, telephone, date.And four in UISchema: firstName, age, telephone, date.They are the same.Each one in JSONSchema has one or less in UISchema.The type in JSONSchema like string, has a few sub-options in string like "updown". We set it in ui:ui:widget(UISchema).And here is my result.The bottom element is the date you mentioned.
[image]

Comment: thank you so much. So you mean I can't have any field even a 'fieldset' just in uiScheama. yes?  all in all I can say jsonform ( https://github.com/jsonform/jsonform ) has this capability but react-jsonschema-form ( https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form ) doesn't . :(

Comment: Yes,you can't have any field even a 'fieldset' just in uiScheama.

Comment: But you can have a field only in schema.@zahrasaffar

Comment: thanks a lot. I wish I could customize it to work like this https://github.com/jsonform/jsonform/wiki I used before in my project :) @Root